# Can an $\infty$-action on a derived affine scheme by an affine group scheme always be strictified?

Tags: derived-algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be an affine derived scheme, say $X = \operatorname{Spec} A$, for $A$ a simplicial commutative ring. Let $G$ be an affine group scheme (classical), say $G = \operatorname{Spec}B$, and let an $\infty$-action of $G$ on $X$ be given in the form of a simplicial diagram $X \leftleftarrows X \times G \cdots$ in the $\infty$-category of derived schemes. This diagram corresponds to a cosimplicial diagram $D$ of the form $A \rightrightarrows A \otimes B \cdots$ in the $\infty$-category of simplicial commutative rings.

Say that we can *strictify* $D$ if it is equivalent to a strictly commutative diagram $D'$ in the model category of simplicial commutative rings such that $D'$ corresponds to a levelwise coaction of $B$ on a simplicial commutative ring $A'$. In other words, we can strictify $D$ if we can, up to equivalence, assume that the equivalences and homotopies which exhibit $D$ as a coaction of $B$ on $A$ are in fact isomorphisms and identities.

The question is: can we always strictify $D$? I suspect the answer is: no, not always, but we can for certain $G$. For example, the answer is yes for $G = \mathbb{G}_m$. I hope to find a counterexample to see that it does not work for general $G$.

Comment: Since it works for $\pi_0A$, have you tried working up the Postnikov tower of $A$ and comparing obstructions at each stage?

Comment: In characteristic $0$, another way to approach it would be to look for obstructions as you work up the lower central series of the pro-unipotent radical of $G$, since strictification should work for pro-reductive groups.